# position close class at the top right of div c?

Tags: css

I have a problem here to position div `close` on the top right corner of div `c`.What would be the best approach for this? [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/vrgdvtfp/)

```css
.c{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:5px;
}

.close{
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class=c>some text<span class=close>x</span></div>
<div class=c>some text<span class=close>x</span></div>
<div class=c>some text<span class=close>x</span></div>
<div class=c>some text<span class=close>x</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.c`

```css
.c {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:5px;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">some text<span class="close">x</span></div>
<div class="c">some text<span class="close">x</span></div>
<div class="c">some text<span class="close">x</span></div>
<div class="c">some text<span class="close">x</span></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also maybe you want to adjust `line-height` on `x` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/130/